# Lifter LMS Sections: Create a page for sections

Tags: wordpress, lms

As far as I understand, Lifter LMS structures the content in: Courses > Sections > Lessons

I can't find a way to add data (ie: Show a page) to a section, my goal is to be able to create a Section page so user can track their progress in that section.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is very vague. What have you tried to accomplish this? This seems like a question you should ask the plugin developer first.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome, I've read the documentation but there's no way to contact the plugin developer, do you have any ideas?

Comment: There are several ways to contact them. [If you are a paid user](https://lifterlms.com/my-account/my-tickets/) or [if you are not](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/lifterlms/)